# pip install openssl/aes.h error and libxml/xmlversion.h error (osx)

Tags: python, django

I have a 'requirements.txt' file and I pip install it. And continue to get these errors:

```
Cryptography_cffi_a269d620xd5c405b7.c:217:10: fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
#include <openssl/aes.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

And this error:

```
fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found
#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

after trying https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did two things to fix this.

```
brew link --force openssl
```

and

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 2):

Now, unfortunately, we can't `brew link --force openssl`. So you can also set environment variables like below:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And do `pip install`.